# how do i solve error could not find a part of the path in c#?

Tags: c#

im looking for a way to ignore this error message ( could not find a part of the path ). i mean my app is working with drive (F:) for exp. so if drive F not exist i will get the error message. how do i ignore or solve this?

my problem is that the path is not a folder and cannot be created...

```
    string fdr = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer);
    string fdrt = System.Environment.MachineName.ToString();
    string fdrir = "F:\\";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of tools you can use:

1. `if (Directory.Exists(pathhere)) dostuff else otherstuff;`
2. `try { dostuff; } catch { doingfailedmessages }`

Both Directory and File give you chances to check for existance, but not for example in file if the file is in use already and locked.  Where as try you try and do it and if it fails the you get to decide.. with the first you can try to eliminate the problem of failing in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. but im new can you explain me with the code? thanks

Comment: that pretty much IS the code :P you dont say what you do with your path that may not be there.. so i cant do that but fill in the "dostuff" or "doingfailedmessages" or "pathhere" and "otherstuff" with what you need it to do and that is your code